# Para todo input, é sempre necessário adicionar um value? E como faço para o value não mudar o placeholder?

Tags: html, html5

Estou criando um formulário simples com HTML puro com o que aprendi no FreeCodeCamp. Mas fiquei um pouco confusa na questão de, se é ou não, necessário colocar value em todo input por que, no final, isso acaba alterando o placeholder que coloquei.

Existe uma regra para a adição do value no input? E se necessário, como faço para isso não alterar meu placeholder?

Meu código está assim:

```
<form>

    <h2>Google</h2>

    <h2>Fazer Login</h2>

    <h4>Use sua conta do Google</h4>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Nome</legend>

        <label for="name">      
            <input id="name" type="text" name="information" placeholder="Digite seu nome" value="name" required>
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Email</legend>

        <label for="email">
            <input id="email" type="email" name="information" placeholder="Digite seu email" value="email" required>
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <a href="#">Esqueceu seu e-mail?</a>

    <p>Não está no seu computador? Use o modo visitante para fazer login com privacidade. <a href="#">Saiba Mais</a>.</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem ?

A propriedade "value" de um input refere-se ao valor contido nela.

No seu caso, você pode criar o input com a propriedade value vazia, (value=""), para que apareça o placeholder corretamente.

Se você criar um input e digitar algum valor dentro, o que estiver escrito no campo passa a ser o "Value", onde automaticamente irá sobrepor a propriedade placeholder.

Answer (score -2):

Este "value" é opcional, não se faz necessário se os dados não forem fixo.

Deixa value=""